# Magento call cms page through anchor tag from phtml file

Tags: php, magento

I want something like this 
 `<a href="<?php echo getcmsurl('Faqs')">FaQ's</a>`

means on clicking FAQ's ,cms page created named `faqs` from admin panel would be linked (called) and displayed.
Or is there any other way ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
  <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('Your cms page identifier'); ?>">My url</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are writing in phtml file then you can use

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('cms page identifer'); ?>">yourlink</a>
```

and if you are writing in static block or page then you can use

```
<a href={{store url="cms page identifer"}}>your link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>Faqs">FaQ's</a>
```