# want to call one phtml file in another phtml file using anchor tag??

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am beginner in magento i want to show some products on home page . also give a link find out more on click that i want to show all product list . please help me .
my new blokes is

```
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("inchoo/onsale/sale.phtml")->toHtml(); 
             ?>
```

Comment: Please see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263663/magento-call-cms-page-through-anchor-tag-from-phtml-file

Answer (score -1):

You have to call in this way:

```
    <?php
$category_id = 13;
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category_id);
    foreach ($children as $category): 
            $categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getEntityId())->getUrl();
            echo '<li><a href="' . $categoryUrl . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

The above one will result the  child categories related to that particular ID.

OR ELSE:

If you want only the url of the particular category then you can call as:

```
 <?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(5)->getUrl() ?>
```

Comment: Can the person 'X', give me the reason of downvoting the answer??So that I can correct it myself...